# DOM-based Vs StAX-based WS-Security

Tags: java, security, cxf, ws-security

I am trying to understand what is **WS-security** and how it works. It uses another term **STS & WS-Trust**.

What is the difference between **DOM-based (in-memory)** and **StAX-based (streaming)** approach to WS-Security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache CXF supports both DOM-based and StAX-based WS-Security implementations. By default it uses the DOM-based approach, but you can switch to use the StAX-based implementation by setting the JAX-WS property "ws-security.enable.streaming" to "true".

The DOM-based approach loads the entire message into memory before applying WS-Security processing. If you are doing complex manipulations of the SOAP message (signing + encrypting different parts etc.) then this is faster than the streaming approach. However, it uses a lot of memory. The streaming approach uses very little memory for large messages compared to the DOM approach, but can be slower to handle more complex tasks.

Comment: Would you be able to provide help for a specific WS-Security/Trust issue our company is having?